# How to enable scrolling in "izimodal"?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, izimodal

I wants to show some data on a modal inside table. I'm using an "izimodal" and when table appends inside the modal, it cannot scroll and gets stuck on the position as it's fixed. I wants to enable scrolling on y axis. how can this issue be solved?

```
//Izimodal properties
    $('#booking-modal').iziModal({
      headerColor: '#00a657', 
      width: '60%', 
      overlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', 
      fullscreen: true, 
      transitionIn: 'fadeInDown', 
      transitionOut: 'fadeOutUp',
      fullscreen: false,
      openFullscreen: false
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want scroll inside the modal?

Answer (score 1):

use this scenario to appeal scroll in your izimodal:
in your css file you can define a CSS class with set overflow for scrolling:

you can use overflow attribute to working with scrolling in your page.
I send a example for you to use that

```css
.scrolling{overflow:auto;}
.scrollingY{overflow-y:visible;}
.scrollingX{overflow-x:hidden}
```

after you define this class you can use this css class in your Html tag with izimodal class like this:

```html
<div class="izimodal scrolling">
</div>
```

I suggest you to use overflow attribute with auto value

Comment: use this link in code pen.
this code with using izimodal and overflow css attribute.
also you can use scroll value instead of visible or hidden.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoLopW